# Why is CMake necessary?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to compile a third party library for use in Visual Studio 2005 Express on Windows 7.

I am having endless error messages which I won't go into to for now.

My real question is - if a c++ library has to be compiled, and a c++ executable can be compiled from that compiled library - why are two compilation steps needed? Surely it'd be easier to just provide the C++ code for the classes etc as some .txt's to compile at our own discretion? To my non computer scientist education the whole c-make fiasco seems like a needless barrier to getting anything done.

Also this business with linking and compiling. Wouldn't it be easier just to set all the directories to the various dependencies manually rather than relying on environment variables etc etc? Since I don't have admin rights, all these things seem like another unnecessary burden?

Answer (score 8):

Source code may be highly portable, but compilers and tools vary significantly across platforms.  The way you would build a shared dynamic library on windows differs greatly from the same on Linux.  CMake, among others provides common tools that accomodate the differences listed above.  It is not a fiasco, it's a solution.